# python: dictionary to .csv-file

Tags: python

I am trying to write a dictionary to a csv file in python.
I've tried nearly every tutorial that I could find but did not get a good result yet.
I want to later edit that file in excel but it looks like this right now:

[image]

My python code:

```
s = file_name
dict = App.get_running_app().get_widget_contents()

with open(s, 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for row in dict.items():
        writer.writerow(row)
```

> 1. What I need is that the key is in column A, and the values are in
>      column B.
> 2. Furthermore each row should be used instead of every second
>      row.
> 3. It would be nice to remove the "," between the key and the
>      value.

I am very happy if someone could help me with this.

Greetings,
Finn

Comment: Please include an example of `dict` that gives some of the results. I'm not sure where those strings of lists are coming from - are they to be split into their own columns? Also, are you on Windows? Is this Python 2 or 3 (changes how you get rid of the blank lines). And finally, it's not a good idea to call your own variables `dict`

Comment: Can you give an example of your  `dict` ?
This should be possible with `csv` native library: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Answer (score 1):

```
s = file_name
dict = App.get_running_app().get_widget_contents()

with open(s, 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(dict.keys())     #Header
    for row, value in dict.items():
        writer.writerow(value)       #Write Values
```

Comment: This will write each value in a separate row. you might want to append each value of a given key into a list, and then join that list with commas and write it once as a row

Answer (score 0):

you can go with

```
s = file_name
dict = App.get_running_app().get_widget_contents()

with open(s, 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for key in dict:
        writer.writerow([key, dict[key]])
```